# jQuery - how to use the “on()” method instead of “live()”?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code (which I've simplified for this) which worked fine alongside jquery-1.7.

```
<div id="sublike-1">Like 1</div>
<div id="sublike-2">Like 2</div>
<div id="sublike-3">Like 3</div>

<div id="sublike-form-1"><input type="text" /> Save 1</div>
<div id="sublike-form-2"><input type="text" /> Save 2</div>
<div id="sublike-form-3"><input type="text" /> Save 3</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).find("div[id^='sublike-']").live('click', function(){
    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $('#sublike-form-' + num).toggle();
});
```

I'm trying to upgrade my code though so I can upgrade my jQuery pack version so I've changed it to onclick.

This doesn't do anything though. It doesn't throw any errors either so I can't see where the problem is.

```
 $(document).find("button[class^='sub-']").on('click','a', function(){
           alert('hi');
        });
```

Any ideas?

Update
This is my button

```
 <button type="button"  id="sub-'+o.id+'"  class="select_address btn btn-
     primary icon  pull-right">Select</button>
```

Comment: Yo are trying to assign click event handler to a `a` tag within `button`...

Comment: I don't see any elements matching the selector `button[class^='sub-']`

Comment: still there is no class in the button type.and also you don't have any a tag inside the button

Comment: @Kate Fernando i don't know how to write it please help me because i am new to web development(learner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code what you are doing is find the button with the class that has 'sub'. And then inside that should be a tag and by clicking that you have to alert 'hi'.

Following is the html that can map with your jquery code.

```
<button type="button"  class="sub-'+o.id+'"><a>Select</a></button>


$(document).find("button[class^='sub-']").on('click','a', function(){
               alert('hi');
            });
```

But remember don't use the above scenario since we are creating separate class for each element. This should not happen. you should use id to create separate ids.

Otherwise you have to change your jquery code with relevant to your html code as below.

```
$(document).find("button[id^='sub-']").on('click', function(){
                   alert('hi');
                });
```

Please let me know if you have any further issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).find("button").on('click','a', function(){..});
```

You are applying the "click" event to an `a` element *within* the button - that does not match your html (and would also be invalid html - links are not valid children of buttons)

You need

```
$("button").on('click',function(){ ... });
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','button', function(){ ... });
```

Note that I took the attribute part out of your selector - it was wrong, but you can target the right button exactly as you would any other selector in jQuery.